# how to update my current route state if component did update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

what i previously done is that I used `router.replace`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { searchParams, category, keywords } = this.props;
    const { router } = this.context;

    router.replace({
      pathname: router.location.pathname,
      state: { searchParams, category, keywords },
    });
}
```

i tried doing it this way but it messes up my router history as it adds another history with the same route. Is there any other way that I can possibly update my current route with the updated state I want without adding more to the list of histories?

I wanted to navigate to other pages and when I press back to this specific route, it retains all the search details that I made before I navigated to other routes

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props !== prevProps) {
     // actions
    }
 }
```

//try if this could help you

Comment: i need to update the router state. this wont help me with anything

Answer (score 0):

You can call `window.history.replaceState` before calling react router's replace method.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { searchParams, category, keywords } = this.props;
    const { router } = this.context;

    window.history.replaceState('','',router.location.pathname);
    router.replace({
      pathname: router.location.pathname,
      state: { searchParams, category, keywords },
    });
}
```